# Fresnel-like integral with parameters

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

I want to compute the following integral:
$$
I(s,t) = \int_0^\infty du\, e^{ i s u^2} u^t.
$$
Using the known expression for the limit of the Fresnel integral (see the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral))
$$
\int_0^\infty dx\, e^{i x^n} x^m = \frac{1}{n} \Gamma\left(\frac{m+1}{n}\right) e^{i\pi \frac{m+1}{2n}}
$$
I can do a change of variables $x^2=sy^2$ for $s>0$, obtaining
$$
\int_0^\infty dy\, e^{isy^2} y^m = \frac{1}{2} s^{-\frac{m+1}{2}}\Gamma\left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right) e^{i\pi \frac{m+1}{4}}
$$
My question is: what happens if $s<0$? Will the integral still converge, will it diverge, or will it evaluate to zero?

Comment: When you say "see the wiki", by any chance would you mean [this wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral)? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, I meant that wiki, under the heading "Generalisations". I will add it to the post.

Comment: I think it suffices to observe that $$I(-s, t) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{i (-s) u^2} u^t \,du = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-i s u^2} u^t \,du = \overline{I(s, t)} .$$

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you.